# UIImagePickerController dismissing when it shouldn't

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to create a custom camera overlay, but am having some problems. The capture view works great, but I would like to show another view where the user can edit the photo after the image is captured. The problem is that when a photo is taken, the view with the photo is automatically dismissed. How would I fix this so that I can show another view controller after the user takes a photo.

Here is how I create the picker:

```
self.cameraPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.cameraPicker.delegate = self;
self.cameraPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.cameraPicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
self.cameraPicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
self.cameraPicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.cameraPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
self.cameraPicker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.cameraPicker.toolbarHidden = YES;
self.cameraPicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720;
self.frontFacing = NO;
self.gridShowing = NO;
self.showingFlash = NO;


// Insert the overlay
CameraOverlayView *overlay = [[CameraOverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
self.cameraPicker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
overlay.delegate = self;

[self.navigationController presentViewController:(UIViewController *)self.cameraPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here is how I take the photo, after this is called, the viewController is dismissed:
, which I do not want:
    [self.cameraPicker takePicture];

Comment: Can you post some code? Also, why can't you just use the default view for the image picker?

Comment: So all I want to do is push another view controller after the photo is taken through `[self.cameraPicker pushViewController:editViewController animated:NO];`, but it just dismisses instead @msgambel

Comment: Do you implement the delegate methods for UIImagePickerController? I believe the default, if you don't implement them, is to just dismiss the view controller.